# Convert Column in CSV File to Histogram of Words In Python

Tags: python, csv

I've got a CSV file containing two columns, and they have no headings/titles. I want to ignore the first column and use the second column (row[1]) to make a histogram of word frequency.

But each entry contains multiple words and other code answers Ive seen on here treats each entry as 1 string so my histogram ends up having the same value for every bar as each string appears once in the file. Ive also tried appending all of the row[1] into a list but that doesnt work either and has the same result of all bars having the same height. I want to make a histogram from data e.g:

```
positive     This dress is great
negative     This coat is terrible
neutral      That dress was ok
```

Would like the histogram bars to then have values of

```
This:2 is:2 dress:2 great:1 etc
```

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have tried using pandas yes, that gave me the results that were incorrect

Comment: `collections.Counter(word for row in reader for word in row[1].split())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
Using a combination of the `csv` module and the `collections.Counter` object:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

data = []
with open('data.csv') as f:
    data = [word for row in csv.reader(f) for word in row[1].lower().split()]

counts = Counter(data)
```

---

**Option 2**
Using `pandas`. Load in your data as a `Series`, specifying no header with `header=False`, and ignoring the first column with `usecols=[1]` (which ignores the 0<sup>th</sup> column).

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, usecols=[1], squeeze=True)
s

0      This dress is great
1    This coat is terrible
2        That dress was ok
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Next, call `str.split` on space, `stack` columns, and then call `value_counts`:

```
s.str.lower().str.split(None, expand=True).stack().value_counts()

this        2
dress       2
is          2
coat        1
ok          1
was         1
great       1
terrible    1
that        1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that if the file is large (really large) you may read it line by line. Try this code. It treats multiple whitespaces as one while splitting, and allows you to ignore case.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re


def read_string_column(csv_file,delimiter=','):
    """
    Read the file line by line
    """
    line = '1'
    while line:
        line = csv_file.readline()
        if len(line.split(delimiter))<2:
            continue
        yield line.split(delimiter)[1]


def add_word_counts(word_dict,new_words):
    """
    Add word counts to a defaultdict
    """
    for word in new_words:
        if word:
            word_dict[word]+=1

def count_words(csv_file,delimiter=',',ignore_case=True):
    """
    Count words.
    delimiter - csv file delimiter
    ignore_case - if True, the text will be read in a lower case
    """
    result_dict = defaultdict(int)
    if ignore_case:
        for words in read_string_column(csv_file,delimiter):
            add_word_counts(result_dict,re.split('\s+',words.lower().strip()))
    else:
        for words in read_string_column(csv_file,delimiter):
            add_word_counts(result_dict,re.split('\s+',words.strip()))
    return result_dict

if __name__=='__main__':
    f = open('1.csv','r')
    print(count_words(f,ignore_case=True))
```